# NDK build error after replacing Tegra Android Development Pack by ndk-r9c

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, tegra

I uninstalled **Tegra Android Development Pack** and manually reconfigured Eclipse's NDK setting as **android-ndk-r9c**.

However, it seems that eclipse is still matching to the removed C:/NVPACK path, may I know how to solve this problem?

> Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - native-activity **

C:\android-ndk-r9c\ndk-build.cmd...

> .....make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r8/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c', needed by`obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/android_native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.o'.  Stop.

Comment: Check your system environment variables, probably some still pointing to the Tegra directory.

Comment: I have removed all Tegra related paths in environment variables and this problem remains, thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry no. I simply removed all eclipse related stuffs and did a clean-installation finally.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem after upgrading TADP. It was still looking for android-ndk-r10 even if the right NDK was now android-ndk-r10c. I deleted all the .a .so .o .o.d in obj\local and rebuilt all, and it worked!